# Spring boot Cloud Embedding Config Server to get properties from Git repo for each request

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

I am using Spring Cloud Embedding Config Server to get the configuration from Git while server startup. Its working fine. Below is my config.

**bootstrap.properties**

spring.application.name= "credentialInfo" 
 
spring.cloud.config.server.bootstrap= "true" 
 
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri= "https://11111@bitbucket.global.company.com/scm/~11111/spring-cloud-config.git" 
 
spring.cloud.config.server.git.username= "aaaa" 
 
spring.cloud.config.server.git.password= "bbbb"

Now I have to get the properties from Git repo for each request with username and password collected from Customers.How can I achieve this ..?

Answer (score 0):

Normally client application get properties from git though config server when startup and when call to "actuator/refresh" endpoint.

Comment: I am using embedded cloud config server currently and it is working fine while server start up. But my requirement is , I have to connect Git repo  with provided username and password from customer. If access is not provided to that customer thenI should throw the error.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get your requirement clearly. Does config server have credential of git or Does customer have ?

Comment: Each Customer will have credential separately , we need to connect the Git with that credential at every request ..

Answer (score 0):

I'm that the requirement as you state its doesn't work well with Spring Boot.
When configurations are read (no matter from where, including the configuration service) they are used to configure spring beans during the startup.

For example, if you have a configuration of, say, db host, this configuration is supposed to be used by bean responsible for database connectivity (DataSource)

The point is that by the time that Application Context starts, beans are already configured.

Its true that some beans having refreashable scope define a custom logic to get "re-initialized" as a consequence of calling /refresh endpoint, but this is not what you're asking for (at least as far as I understood)

Instead you say, that the client does something during the application startup and this action should lead to beans change. This is potentially a very expensive operation and I don't think you should go in this direction. Usually beans are not re-created during runtime (of scope singleton, and the chances are that most of the beans are of this scope)